# How to create dynamic route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I create compare page for products,

I need create route for compare page, How to create dynamic route in `Laravel 5.3`?

For example:

```
https://www.mywesite.com/Compare/DKP-181451/DKP-254287/DKP-254282/DKP-227429/DKP-254282
```

This page is 5 product for compare.

Or:

```
https://www.mywesite.com/Compare/DKP-181451/DKP-254287
```

This page is 2 product for compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will probably work:

```
 Route::get("Compare/{any}", function ($any) {
       $productsToCompare = explode("/",$any);
       // Compare products.


 })->where("any", ".*");
```

Comment: Hi, What is the meaning of this? `->where("any", ".*");` ?

Comment: It means that the parameter named `any` should match regular expression `.*` (which means 0 or more of any character)